# JavaFX: TextArea promptText location doesn't update if we dynamically change textArea width

Tags: javafx

I want to create simple `TextArea` with `RIGHT_TO_LEFT` nodeOrientation. It's done.
But when I resize main container(window) `promptText` in `rightTextArea` doesn't move with a right textArea border. The same with a cursor.

```
    public class RightToLeft extends Application {

    @Override public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPromptText("hello world");

        TextArea rightTextArea = new TextArea();
        rightTextArea.setPromptText("Hello world");
        rightTextArea.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);


        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setPromptText("Text field prompt");
        textField.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textArea, rightTextArea, textField);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vbox));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas, please, share :-) Thanks

Comment: It's a known bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189167  
The only workaround I know of is to change some other visual property of the `TextArea` to force it to recalculate its bounds - for example, I change the font size to a smaller size and back to the original size after every resize. It's a dirty hack, but it works (until the bug is fixed).

Comment: Thank you, @Itai